# Horizontal Scrollview with pages in Android

Tags: android, scrollview

I am looking for a behavior very similar to ios where we can scroll horizontally to see multiple pages (like a walkthrough/demo). In ios we can do it with UIScrollView and PageControl but not sure how can that be done in Android?

I don't mind if it's not possible to add the bullets of PageControl. I am more concerned about the pages type behavior of scrollview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this article on viewPager, I think it has the something as you require.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewFlipper in android to scroll or swipe between the different layouts....

Try searching "android ViewFlipper onFling()" on google..

http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/tag/view-flipper/